# ARIMAX with Exogenous Variable modeled using Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process

Tags: python, arima, modeling, econometrics, stochastic-processes

I have a question with regard to building ARIMA with Exogenous Variables (ARIMAX) models where one of the Exogenous Variables is to be modeled using the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

I recently read an academic paper which stated "Oil price is modelled by the mean-reverting Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process and serves as the exogenous variable in the ARIMAX models for natural gas and downstream plastic prices". [Ren, H., Zhou, W., Wang, H. et al. An energy system optimization model accounting for the interrelations of multiple stochastic energy prices. Ann Oper Res 316, 555–579 (2022).](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10479-021-04229-3)

Similarly, one of the exogenous variables I am forecasting seems to exhibit mean-reverting characteristics and thus, I would like to model it using the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (OU) process. Upon doing this and generating the forecasted values of the exogenous variables from the OU process (for the future forecast period), how do I amend the Python code to get the ARIMA function to accept and use my OU-generated forecast period exogenous variables in the forecasting of the Y-variable in the ARIMAX model? Do I just make the exog dataframe/series longer than the endogenous dataframe? (Longer because it also contains the OU-generated exogenous variable values)

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ARIMA

# Fit ARIMAX model
model = ARIMA(data['endogenous_variable'][:train_size],
              order=(p, d, q),
              exog=data['forecasted_exog'][:train_size])
model_fit = model.fit()
```